# Can we delete older records from memsql table automatically?

Tags: pinterest, singlestore

We are using memsql streamliner for our real time data pipeline as part of POC.Is there any way in memsql settings through which we can  specify the rule to delete the 1 week older data from memsql automatically?

Answer (score 0):

No. This logic must be performed elsewhere, in an application, `cron` job, etc.